# From SQL result some vouchers not required

Tags: sql-server

I need to get ledger from a table. Its working, but its picking some rows which I do not required, how I can drop these rows.

Here is detail scenerio
I have the following rows in table

[image: I have the following rows]

When I execute the statement `select * from MyTable where AccountCode=1001`

I gives me the following rows.

[image: It gives the following rows]

According to the SQL statement result is fine, but I do not need the rows in result which have yellow background as it have same debit and credit Account Code and the Amount.

So I need to drop the PV voucher from result which have same Account Code and Amount.

Please help to me to resolve it.

Here is the DDL

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyEntries](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [AccountCode] [int] NULL,
    [Voucher] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Dr] [real] NULL,
    [Cr] [real] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[MyEntries] ON
INSERT [dbo].[MyEntries] ([Id], [AccountCode], [Voucher], [Description], [Dr], [Cr]) VALUES (1, 1001, N'R.10001', N'some desc', 100, 0)
INSERT [dbo].[MyEntries] ([Id], [AccountCode], [Voucher], [Description], [Dr], [Cr]) VALUES (2, 1005, N'R.10001', N'some desc', 0, 100)
INSERT [dbo].[MyEntries] ([Id], [AccountCode], [Voucher], [Description], [Dr], [Cr]) VALUES (3, 1001, N'PV.2587', N'some desc', 500, 0)
INSERT [dbo].[MyEntries] ([Id], [AccountCode], [Voucher], [Description], [Dr], [Cr]) VALUES (4, 1001, N'PV.2587', N'some desc', 0, 500)
INSERT [dbo].[MyEntries] ([Id], [AccountCode], [Voucher], [Description], [Dr], [Cr]) VALUES (5, 5002, N'B.12584', N'some desc', 200, 0)
INSERT [dbo].[MyEntries] ([Id], [AccountCode], [Voucher], [Description], [Dr], [Cr]) VALUES (6, 1001, N'B.12584', N'some desc', 0, 200)
INSERT [dbo].[MyEntries] ([Id], [AccountCode], [Voucher], [Description], [Dr], [Cr]) VALUES (7, 1001, N'PV.2587', N'some desc', 500, 0)
INSERT [dbo].[MyEntries] ([Id], [AccountCode], [Voucher], [Description], [Dr], [Cr]) VALUES (8, 1003, N'PV.2587', N'some desc', 0, 500)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[MyEntries] OFF
```

Comment: As a helpful tip, when providing data for a SQL question don't post them as an image; other users can't use that. Instead consider posting DDL and consumable sample data. [Forum Etiquette: How to post a T-SQL Question](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Best+Practices/61537/). If you post well, it'll greatly increase the chances of you getting an answer, or more comprehensive ones. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can try using `SUM` as a window function over a partition of account code and voucher.  Then, we can retain records whose credit/debit difference is not zero.

```
SELECT
    [Account Code], Voucher, Description, Debit, Credit
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
        SUM(COALESCE(Credit, 0) - COALESECE(Debit, 0)) OVER (
            PARTITION BY [Account Code], [Voucher]) AS running_sum
    FROM yourTable
) t
WHERE running_sum <> 0;
```